# PLSQL : Using Member of with Nested Table of type NUMBER - PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name

Tags: oracle, plsql

Working with collections in plsql for the first time.

Declaraton of nested table :

```
TYPE nt_orders IS TABLE OF NUMBER 
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

nt_invc_orders nt_orders;
```

Where I am using `member of`

```
    IF( 12345 member of nt_orders) THEN
        nt_scb_temp_objects(i).invc_ref := p_invc_ref;
    END IF;
```

NOTE : For now, I have entered 12345 as my search, in reality this will be a variable(of Number type) stored value.

**ERROR : PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your collection is actually not a nested table, it's an associative array. You should remove `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;` to make it a nested table. Moreover, `MEMBER OF` function doesn't work with associative arrays. Second problem is you are searching for the element with  the collection type - `nt_orders`  as the right argument, which is wrong. It should be the nested table variable.

```
declare
TYPE nt_orders IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
nt_invc_orders nt_orders := nt_orders(12345);

begin
    IF  12345 member of nt_invc_orders THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('found');
     else 
     dbms_output.put_line('not found');
    END IF;
end;
/
```

Output

```
found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```